# How to turn off graying out unused usings?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How (supposing it's even possible) to turn off the Visual Studio 2015 feature to gray out unused usings (usings in C#, Imports in VB) ??  I like all the other highlight / syntax checking / auto compile stuff in VS, I'm only trying to turn this off specifically to graying out unused usings.

I can't seem to find an option for this specifically in the VS 2015 menus.  If anybody is aware of such an option please advise as to location.

Comment: You could delete them

Comment: You either need them in order to compile, in which case they are normal colour, or you don't, in which case you can safely delete them.

Comment: Or add a statement to your code that requires the `Using`

Comment: If you have preprocessor sections of code (like an "#if DEBUG") VS will fail to detect usings required by the block that is not activated. If this is your scenario, I would recommend adding fully qualified names inside that conditional block, in case someone tries to "clean up the 'unused' usings".

Answer (score 13):

You can disable it on a project-by-project basis. Open your project references > Analyzers and turn off `IDE0005`. This will disable the 'visual cue' (grayed out hint) but you will still be able to select the quick action 'Remove unnecessary usings' if you put the cursor on one of these. Don't think it's possible to disable this (and you really shouldn't anyway).

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the unused `using` is actually useful (i.e. shortens names of types in documentation comments when you pause your mouse over a member outside debug mode).  You can suppress the warning for those usings with `#pragma warning disable`:

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0005 // Using directive is unnecessary
```

To resume the behavior in the file, you would use `#pragma warning restore`.

```
#pragma warning restore IDE0005 // Using directive is unnecessary
```

Do be warned, as of VS 2017 15.6.6, the menu option for `Remove and Sort Usings` will ignore the `#pragma warning disable` directives.  As I think this is a bug, I will be submitting a roslyn issue.