# Visual Studio C# Code colour of this

Tags: visual-studio

I have been fiddling with the colours of the various C# items in my new Visual Studio 2017 (Community) using the Tools->Options->Font and Colors. Everything is fine apart from the `this` keyword.

Does anyone happen to know which of the Display Items one can change the colour of will affect the `this` keyword?

Comment: Maybe the [SemanticColorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer) provides this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is analyzer rule

> IDE0003 Name can be simplified

with the option "Remove 'this' qualification".

I found no way to set a different color, but the rule can be deactivated so the dimming is not applied: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32144170/1132334

This does specifically target `this` (or `Me` in VB).

Answer (score 2):

It's just a keyword, the same as all the others. I don't think you can tell VS to highlight it differently to other keywords.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more coding with this new toy, it seems that *unnecessary* `this` keywords are coloured differently from necessary ones. The same applies to unnecessary `using` statements.

As Jon Skeet says, `this` is a keyword and coloured as the other keywords, but it seems the unnecessary ones aren't. Since I don't like the colour this provides some incentive for getting rid of them.