# Why is C# code partially greyed out in the Visual Studio 2015 editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is how sample C# code looks in my VS 2015 configuration:

[image]

The statements in the rectangles are greyed-out.  What is the meaning for this?  [Per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32144170/360840), I know that there are rules under References->Analyzers, but I cannot tell which active rule produces this result.

**EDIT:**

Per Hans Passant's guidance:

[image]

Comment: Click the lightbulb icon in the left rail for advice.  It will teach you how to use the Elvis operator.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you! The lightbulb explanation was: **IDE1005 Delegate invocation can be simplified.** If you provide your comment as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 3):

The analyzer is suggesting that your code should be functioning also without those lines.

I assume it is able to determine that `Tick` and `Finished` are never **null**. Variables you introduced are superfluous, too.

Comment: _ Tick and Finished are never null_ Not quite..