# Stop Visual Studio from warning about unused 'using' statements

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

**The proposed duplicate is not one. Until the latest update (16.10) the three dots were not there, the `using`s were just grayed out (as in the duplicate). Please stop suggesting useless duplicates.**

How do I stop Visual Studio from warning about unused `using` statements (by the three dots under them)?

e.g.

[image]

And no option to ignore it exists:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143710? I appreciate that it might not since that's a project-by-project basis rather than overall.

Comment: @Llama It also doesn't help. Please see my edit.

Comment: Witch Framwork ?
Could you add an .editorconfig in your project / solution ?

Comment: I found this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/28114), which may be of use to you. To learn more about rule sets, visit [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2019).

Comment: `The proposed duplicate is not one.` why? Warnings like this *are* disabled through `#pragma` directives or build settings. This is nothing new. You may be using a different analyzer (VS? Resharper? Roslynator?) but all of them are controlled in the same way.

Comment: You may have found a bug that appeared only now in 16.10, and will disappear with a fix. That may mean that none of the ways to turn of the warning will work and you'll have to wait for the fix. It *doesn't mean* that the docs, pragmas and settings that disable warnings are useless. They're your only options. If the `#pragma` doesn't work, perhaps the build symbols will. Or the rulesets

Comment: It might be a bug or it might not. This is a website that developers can use to ask questions about programming and programming tools.

Comment: I think you'll get a better response from the Roslyn project directly. They'll either know a workaround, or discuss this as a request for changing the behaviour of the product in a future release. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn