# How to hide the ... that appeared everywhere in Visual Studio 16.10?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How to hide the `...` that appeared everywhere in Visual Studio 16.10?

e.g.

[image]

It appears for unused `using`s, expression value not assigned, and *many* more.

[I'm NOT asking how to turn off graying out of unused `using`s.]

Comment: If it helps, I believe that means that there's an available code-fix at that position. So the latest update (or SDK, since that was updated too) looks to have more available or on-by-default analyzers. I know there's a way to turn those off individually or en masse but don't recall how off hand.

Comment: I have Resharper installed (which does it's own syntax, helpful hints stuff), so I may be a little off.  But, I believe that that is VS telling you there's a better (or at least, another) way to do what you are doing.  For example, if at the betting of a method, I type `int i = 0;`, something will put three dots under the `int`.  If I hover over the three dots, I get an explanation that it represents an Int32, but also a note that _use 'var' (built in types)_.  If I click above the three dots, a light-bulb appears in the left margin.  If I click the bulb, it gives me options like "Use var".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dots like that, along with squiggly underlines, are coming from diagnostics issued by the compiler and analyzers.

Each diagnostic has its own identifier code such as `CS1234` or `IDE1234`, etc.

You can configure the severity of each of these as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019

The easiest way is to add/edit your `.editorconfig` file and put the following in:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.<rule ID>.severity = <severity>
```

Where `<rule ID>` is the diagnostic ID, and `<severity>` is one of `none`, `silent`, `suggestion`, `warning` or `error`.

This gives you very fine grained control over these kinds of tips in your solution.

If you put the `.editorconfig` file in the root of your repo, it will apply to all projects in the solution.

---

Here's an example of using the lightbulb menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) to configure the severity of a diagnostic with code VSTHRD002:

[image]

There's also a section "Suppress ..." which lets you suppress a specific instance of the diagnostic, in contrast to changing the severity which applies across a broader scope.

Note you have have multiple `.editorconfig` files. For example, if all your unit tests are under a `test` folder, you could drop an `.editorconfig` file in there that has more relaxed rules.

Comment: And if you want an easy way to do this, use `Ctrl`+`.` on that line and select "Suppress or configure issues"

Comment: @HansKeﬆing good point, I extended my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing This does not work in the case of using statements. See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67762142/939213).